# Weird Mac Address at Windows 2003 DHCP Server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, dhcp, android, cellular

I am trying to configure a reservation for my Galaxy.

The problem is that my DHCP is giving out an IP address to an obviously invalid MAC address (Galaxy Mac Address) - Please note attached screenshot . Why just two characters Address?

Why is Windows 2003 Server recognizing this MAC Address?

The Wireless router recognizes the correct address.

Is anyone having the same problem?

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24848

http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/media-problems/samsung-ace-weird-mac-address-at-windows-2003-dhcp-server/?action=dlattach;attach=1309;image

http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/media-problems/samsung-ace-weird-mac-address-at-windows-2003-dhcp-server/?action=dlattach;attach=1311;image

Answer (score 1):

If you know the MAC address, you should be able to manually  enter it as a reservation in DHCP.  Is that not possible?  If it is, does it work and does DHCP continue to assign an IP based on the unusual 2 character address?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be entered as a reservation in DHCP. However, the device never receives the address it should, unless the IP address is entered into it manually. 
For example, even if "john-galaxy", MAC 0123456789ab, is assigned an address, it will still be receiving temporary (dud) addresses from the pool. Looking at the address leases, I would see "john-galaxy" listed with a temporary, automatically-assigned address (that is blocked from the internet), along with a two-character MAC. It would also be listed under permanent reservations with its correct IP and MAC addresses, but it wouldn't actually use those.